# QGIS failed with error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

Tags: openlayers-2, qgis

I have some shapefiles from vegetation types in QGIS and I wanted to put a Google map in the background, so I installed the OpenLayers plugin. But every time I tried to load the map, there's an error message:

```
"failed with error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits".
```

What to do then?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible that QGIS is not recognising the CRS of your shapefiles correctly. Try right-clicking on each one in the layers panel and setting its CRS correctly. It looks as if the shapefiles might be projected, but that QGIS "thinks" that they are geographic (lat/lon).

Comment: Thank you, i think you got it..and i had to open the background map first for some reason. But now it works!