# Issue loading layer from OpenLayers plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I installed the OpenLayers plugin in QGIS and tried to load one of the layers. Regardless of which layer I try to load, I am getting an error message. See example: 
[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: For me a restart of QGIS always fixed this error...

Answer (score 1):

It may be a problem with the CRS in some of the layers. I hope this post could help you: 
[QGIS failed with error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23255/qgis-failed-with-error-latitude-or-longitude-exceeded-limits)